# Matlab - How to check the existence of a handle

Tags: matlab

is there any way to check if a handle exists or not? So something like: if I didnt previously declare a handle, I want a 0 as output and else a 1.

I tried ishandle,isvalid,isfield,isempty but they all don't work on a "non-existent field" so I receive an error if I didnt declare the handle..
"Reference to non-existent field 'SP'."

If I try the "exist name" function it just works for variables but not for handles

So:

```
handle.a=figure;
exist handle.a;
```

returns a 0

while

```
handle.a=figure;
a=handle.a;
exist a
```

returns a 1

but I'm looking for:

```
handle.a=figure;
exist handle.a
```

ans=1

```
%without setting the handle:
exist handle.a
```

ans=0

I hope my post is understandable.
Thank you for your help! Klaus

Comment: Use `ishandle` or `isvalid`

Comment: And read the documentation for `exist`. It doesn't return a logical (`true` or `false`) value.

Comment: Like I wrote in the post, I tried ishandle and isvalid. With both I get "Reference to non-existent field 'SP'." And I know that exist gives different numbers but I just want a different output for both mentioned cases (not an error)

Comment: You need to do this in two steps. exist('handle') && ishandle(handle.a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me rephrase: You are assigning a handle to a field of a structure. Now you want to test whether there is a valid handle in the field, and guard against everything that could be wrong: (1) there's no field, (2) it's empty, (3) it's an array instead of a scalar, (4) it's not a handle, (5) it's not a valid handle.

Thus:

```
tf = isfield(handle,'a') && isscalar(handle.a) && ishandle(handle.a);
```

Of course, if you know that some of the conditions can never occur, you can drop the respective tests.

Comment: Just a comment: if one uses `isscalar` to test the size of an object, there's no point in using `isempty` (a scalar cannot be empty). Also, `ishandle` is meant to be used on graphics handles, while `isvalid` is meant to be used on objects that inherit the `handle` class (not the same thing, and actually testing for both will generate errors). I'm going to correct your answer, if you don't mind.

Comment: @CST-Link: I wanted to make the empty/scalar tests explicit, but you're right, it's not necessary. At least on newer versions of Matlab implementing handle graphics, `isvalid` does not throw an error on handle to graphics, and returns `false` upon testing a handle to a figure that is being deleted. However, since `ishandle` returns false as well in that context, `isvalid` is indeed redundant.

Comment: I've created a MATLAB chat room for us to discuss things MATLAB related, or for discussions that span beyond the limitations of a single comment. Visit us when you have time! - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab